# Responsive Collection of Small Images

Tags: css, responsive-design

Typically for collecting data I'd use a table but it seems to have a lot of issues. My goal is have a collection of images 5 wide and 10 tall. Images about 150x150. However when I resize the browser the images are places in a scrollbox. Is there an easier way to group these images besides a table? Should I use media queries to resize it to be two wide at a particular screen size?

Comment: Posting your current code would help.

Comment: I'm currently just using a single row five column table and experimenting with css and temporary images, didn't include it as it's very barebones. I suppose my question comes down to: would the best way to handle this be by switching to two columns when the width hits a certain threshold, or is there an accepted better way to handle this problem? If anyone knows of any resources for changing the amount of columns with a media query i'd appreciate it

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a table and not float:left?

Comment: No particular reason. The images are all logo's for particular companies and contain a line of text underneath them with their name. My goal is to have them displaying across the page at full screen width and ideally move into a two column display when the screen shrinks. I may be over thinking the problem. How would a float: left be useful?

Comment: looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h3646Ljk/ ?

Comment: Make sure to add a fixed height and width to the divs and add overflow: hidden by the way (or you ll be in trouble with longer company names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

This is a simple code for a basic gallery. It is responsive and if your images width and height are defined and all the same, this code will do.

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  /* to align your elements in the middle of the page */
}
.gallery:after {
  /* To clear floated elements after your gallery */
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px 15px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**SOLUTION 2**

This is a fully responsive solution. In the first solution, your `li` will always be the same size, when it's too big it will just go down one line. In the second solution, the width will adapt depending on the screen size so that you can force 2, 3, 4 or 5 `li` per line. Study this code and adjust it to your needs. To better understand resize your browser window with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7xokjk0/1/

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 1% 20px .5%;
}
.gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .gallery li {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .gallery li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  .gallery li {
    width: 17%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <figcaption>Some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```